# Can Spring XD be used as a message broker for notifications?

Tags: java, spring

I have to implement a notification system within a Java Spring app with angular for a front end. I was advised on using Spring XD as the message broker. However after looking at it, I am unsure if this would be a good strategy. It might be possible but will look like a hack.

EDIT: I have a simple use-case. On the web app if user A does an action X, then I need to notify user B about action X using notifications in the web app (if the user B is currently logged in), through GCM and through SMS.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Spring XD is a framework which allows us to communicate with several different Message Broker (among other things that it does). So, Spring XD itself cannot act as a MB Server. As a MB server, you have several options like ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Kafka....

If you are planning to build a message oriented system from ground up, then Spring XD could be a good choice. If you are just looking for adding a new feature in existing application, you can achieve communication to any of the above MQ servers using Spring Integration (recommend you check Spring Integration Java DSL). This way you will be easily integrate it with existing application.